# Limit database input choice using Doctrine

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine

I have something like this:

```
/**
 * @var string
 * @ORM\Column(name="item", type="string", length=255, nullable=true)
 * @JMSS\Type("string")
 */
protected $item;
```

I need to somehow limit what can be written into `$item`. Something like:

```
/**
* @Allowed {'Peter', 'Jack', 'Adam' }
*/
```

So only Peter, Jack or Adam could be written on the DB

I see no way to do this after reading the documentation. Any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `@Assert\Choice` [annotation](https://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/constraints/Choice.html).

More about validation [here](https://symfony.com/doc/current/validation.html).